# Как предотвратить закрытие приложения через диспетчер задач (Kill Process)?

Tags: c++, windows

Есть приложения, которые не прибиваются через "Завершить процесс" в диспетчере задач.

**Как это реализовать в своём приложении на C++?** Это должна быть служба, которая мониторит процесс, или параллельное приложение, или есть ещё какие-то способы, о которых я не знаю?... Подскажите пожалуйста возможные варианты.

Comment: вы уверены, что они не завершаются? идентификатор процесса остается таким же?

Comment: Не знаю насчёт идентификаторов, Просто нажимаешь завершить процесс, а он продолжает работать. Например антивирус какой-нибудь...

Comment: скорей всего он перезапускается. проверьте идентификатор процесса до и после.

Comment: антивирусы добавляют в ядро свой драйвер. А он уже может и не давать прибить приложение. А может просто перезапускать приложение.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это возможно.
Вы можете установить процесс как критический, однако, это требует прав администратора.

Используйте NtSetInformationProcess: http://www.codingvision.net/tips-and-tricks/c-make-a-critical-process-bsod-if-killed (пример на C# - не трудно на C++ перевести).

P.S.: Да и антивирус на такое решение у меня не орал (тогда юзал KTS 2015).